# Gridview разная высота элементов

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, xaml

Пытаюсь реализовать многоуровневую таблицу соревнований. 5 судей дают оценки каждому участнику в двух выступлениях по 2-м категориям.

Баллы выводятся через Grid, но Имя, суммарный балл и средний балл находятся в отдельных столбцах.

XAML разметка:

```
<ListView Name="DGMain" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.PanningDeceleration="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Имя">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{DynamicResource CellStyle}" Content="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Баллы">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="1" Style="{DynamicResource CellStyle}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="2" Style="{DynamicResource CellStyle}"/>

                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Техника:" Style="{DynamicResource CellStyle}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Презентация:" Style="{DynamicResource CellStyle}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Content="Техника:" Style="{DynamicResource CellStyle}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Content="Презентация:" Style="{DynamicResource CellStyle}"/>

                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridTStyle}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=P1.PointsT[0], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridTStyle}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=P1.PointsT[1], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridTStyle}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=P1.PointsT[2], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridTStyle}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=P1.PointsT[3], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridTStyle}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=P1.PointsT[4], Mode=OneWay}"/>

                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridPStyle}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=P1.PointsP[0], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridPStyle}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=P1.PointsP[1], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridPStyle}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=P1.PointsP[2], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridPStyle}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=P1.PointsP[3], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridPStyle}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=P1.PointsP[4], Mode=OneWay}"/>


                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridTStyle}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=P2.PointsT[0], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridTStyle}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=P2.PointsT[1], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridTStyle}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=P2.PointsT[2], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridTStyle}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=P2.PointsT[3], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridTStyle}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=P2.PointsT[4], Mode=OneWay}"/>

                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridPStyle}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=P2.PointsP[0], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridPStyle}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=P2.PointsP[1], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridPStyle}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=P2.PointsP[2], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridPStyle}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=P2.PointsP[3], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridPStyle}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=P2.PointsP[4], Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Среднее">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridOverallStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=P1.Middle, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource GridOverallStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=P2.Middle, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Сумма">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource GridOverallStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=P1.Overall, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource GridOverallStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=P2.Overall, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

В результате получилось следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на фотографии, имя, средние и суммарные баллы не по центру... Хотелось бы, чтобы ячейка для сммарного балла и среднего балла занимала столько же места, сколько занимает вся колонка по выступлению... Но, т.к. они в разных элементах, затрудняюсь предположить как это можно сделать (если это вообще возможно)

Не могли бы вы подсказать, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно задать выравнивание контента для `ListViewItem`. Тогда выравнивание корневого элемента в `DataTemplate` будет работать (по умолчанию `Stretch`).

```
<ListView>

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- ... -->

    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>

                <!-- ... -->

                <GridViewColumn Header="Сумма">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Rows="2" Columns="1">
                                <TextBox Text="11,73"/>
                                <TextBox Text="9,73"/>
                            </UniformGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Здесь для простоты я использовал `UniformGrid`, но вы можете использовать `Grid` со строками, у которых `Height="*"`. `StackPanel` растягивать элементы не будет.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Проблема решена